# drop content just under the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button in my HTML, and I want some content to appear just right under that button, and it should be on top of all other content, and shouldn't move any existing content. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery in your client side code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but check out this example for using the CSS property `position`:

```
<p>Other content</p>
<button>Button Text</button><br />
<div style="position:absolute; color:red;">Absolute Text</div>
<p>Other content</p>
```

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/tczc5/

Answer (score 2):

Put that content into a div and use

```
position:absolute;
```

It should look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:relative;">
  <button ..... >
  <div class="yourContent" style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:0px;">
    <!-- put your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to show this content only after pressing the button, then change it to:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="yourButton" ..... >
  <div class="yourContent hidden">
    <!-- put your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Define css styles in stylesheet like:

```
.wrapper {position:relative;}
.wrapper .yourButton {position:absolute; top:0; left:0}
.yourContent {position:absolute; top:20px; left:0}
.hidden {display:none;}
```

And then javascript (using jQuery):

```
$('.yourButton').click(function(){
    $('.yourContent').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

Just a simple example, that you will have to tweak.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/) is a good article on css position can be found on alistapart.

Looking at your question a must read if you're not 100% familiar with positioning.